# How to label a FeatureLayer using ArcGIS Javascript 4.3

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm struggling to determine how to label a FeatureLayer using ArcGIS Javascript 4.3.

I've found the FeatureLayer API reference [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html).

One of the FeatureLayer properties is labelingInfo of type LabelClass[]. The labelingInfo details says that "There is no support for labeling in 2D. Labeling is only supported in 3D SceneViews." I want to add labels to a 2D map.

I've also found the [TextSymbol Class](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-symbols-TextSymbol.html), which says it is "used to define the graphic for displaying labels on a FeatureLayer." If that's the case, I can't figure out what FeatureLayer property to include a TextSymbol.

Comment: Can you use a MapImageLayer instead of a FeatureLayer? Supports labeling 2D, https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-mapimagelayer-dynamic-labels/index.html